# Check/Wait for the invoked application to be open

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-8.0

I can't get the programmatic call to the Docker-Desktop application to wait until it has fully opened.

***What I'm trying to do:***

I'm here because I have a personal project in hand, which revolves around docker-desktop.

I'm developing in C#/Winform for .net8.0 a user interface that allows for the automated deployment of a LAMP server system.

It is something similar to what configuration scripting would be but at the docker level.

The complexity that I am facing right now is that to correctly deploy and/or the characteristics that I need from the lamp server system, I need to activate/modify some settings in docker desktop (I don't know if it can be done through direct commands to the Docker engine) to achieve The task I am working with is first:

> C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\setting.json

***What have I achieved?***

I programmatically alter the json making these changes:

```
Dictionary<string, string> settingsToReplace = new()
{
    { "\"exposeDockerAPIOnTCP2375\": false,", "\"exposeDockerAPIOnTCP2375\": true," },
    { "\"updateHostsFile\": false,", "\"updateHostsFile\": true," },
    { "\"displayedOnboarding\": false,", "\"displayedOnboarding\": true," },
    { "\"licenseTermsVersion\": 0,", "\"licenseTermsVersion\": 2," },
    { "\"noWindowsContainers\": true,", "\"noWindowsContainers\": false," },
    { "\"runWinServiceInWslMode\": false,", "\"runWinServiceInWslMode\": true," }
};

foreach (var setting in settingsToReplace)
{
    if (jsonContent.Contains(setting.Key))
    {
        jsonContent = jsonContent.Replace(setting.Key, setting.Value); // with this I exchange the json values
        update = true;
    }
}
```

***What I'm trying and it doesn't work:***

So far everything is going well... the first real problem is restarting the docker-desktop environment and all its services or those that are necessary for it to recognize the new settings.

I have tried to run the following commands:

```
string dockerDesktopPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), @"Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe");

await run.RunCommand("Stop-Process -Name \\\"Docker Desktop\\\"", "powershell",true); //Command #1
await run.RunCommand("Stop-Service -Name \\\"com.docker.service\\\"", "powershell",true); //Command #1
await run.RunCommand("Start-Service -Name \\\"com.docker.service\\\"", "powershell",true); //Command #1
await run.RunCommand("Start-Process -FilePath \\\"" + dockerDesktopPath + "\\\"", "powershell",true); //Command #1
```

from the C# application and tried to execute the following commands, calling them through a PowerShell instance:

```
public async Task RunCommand(string script, string command = "powershell", Boolean show = false, string? workDirectory = null)
{
string arguments = $"-Command \"Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force ; {script}";

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new(command)
{
    Arguments = arguments,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas",
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

Process process = new() { StartInfo = processStartInfo };

process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        //write on console for tracking
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        //write on console for tracking
    }
};

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

await process.WaitForExitAsync();
}
```

***My questions:***

As you can see, my C# implementation may not be that of an expert and I do not know the full scope of the native methods that are executed or accessible in the framework. I would like to be able to consecutively detect when the completion of each occurs. one of the 4 commands, apparently the commands are sent but they overlap, causing instability when I execute the fourth command.

***Update***

the VS2022 and C# application have requirement to run with elevated user permission: administrator.

Comment: Have you tried added some logging or console output logic in the `*DataReceived` handlers? Might be able to find out what's going wrong if you look :)

Comment: Of course, to do tracking I print in the console, since there are other places where I need to execute commands such as when installing chocolatey and/or mkcert... anyway, for everything that has an output I log it into the console, but it just so happens that these ***4 commands do not generate output.*** i implement: `process.OutputDataReceived` and `process.ErrorDataReceived`

Comment: To bring closure to this question: From what I can tell, the answer now fully addresses your question _as asked_: it addresses why your application, if run _non-elevated_, cannot work, and offers a workaround.
If it is run _elevated_, then output capturing _should_ work. If that is the premise, I encourage you to ask a _new_ question that states this explicitly, and removes the distracting aspects (`UseShellExecute = false`,
`Verb = "runas"`). Similarly, per our chat, please ask a new question for _follow-up questions_ relating to process-lifetime tracking.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface**:

- Your *immediate* problem is that in order to launch an *elevated* process - via `Verb = "RunAs"` - you must set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, otherwise `Verb` is ignored.

  - If you do so, `CreateNoWindow = true` will be ignored, because elevated processes *invariably* run in a *new window*.
- *Fundamentally*, however, with `UseShellExecute` set to `true`, you can *not* use `RedirectStandardOutput` and `RedirectStandardError` to capture output, which is the problem discussed below.

(In effect, your code ran the processes (a) *without* elevation and (b) therefore *should* have allowed you to capture their output, but the fact that that didn't work is a problem not worth solving, given that you *need elevation*, which requires the workaround discussed below.)

---

The core problem is that **you cannot *directly* capture an *elevated* process' output streams from a *non-elevated* process**. This constraint, as reflected in the .NET APIs and as detailed below, comes down to limitations in the Windows APIs.

- Conversely, **if your *own* process is *itself elevated*, so will be any child process** launched by it (with the same user identity, as happens by default).
- If you can assume that your own process is elevated, then setting/leaving `UseShellExecute` at `false` (in which case you should eliminate `Verb = "RunAs"`, to avoid confusion) *does* allow you to capture a by-default-and-invariably-also-elevated child process' output directly, via setting `.RedirectStandardOutput` and `.RedirectStandardError` to `true` (if *both* are set to `true`, you don't need `CreateNoWindow = true`, because by definition there will then be no output to the *console*).

**If your own process is *non-elevated*:**

In .NET terms, setting `.UseShellExecute = true` on a [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) instance - which is the prerequisite for being able to use `.Verb = "RunAs"` in order to run *elevated* - means that you cannot use the `.RedirectStandardOutput` and `.RedirectStandardError` properties for capturing the launched process' output.

- In fact, trying to start a process with *both* `.RedirectStandardOutput` and/or `.RedirectStandardError` set to `true` *and* `.UseShellExecute` set to `true` causes an *exception* that specifically says that these property (groups) cannot be used together.

  - As such, the constraint isn't about *elevation* per se, but about the use of `.UseShellExecute` (whether or not the `.Verb` property is also set makes no difference), i.e. about performing a [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) operation, ultimately via the [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) WinAPI function.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Conversely, unfortunately, filling in the `.Verb` property without also setting `.UseShellExecute` set to `true` cause the `.Verb` property to be *quietly ignored*, meaning that *no* elevation happens if `.Verb = "RunAs"` isn't explicitly combined with `.UseShellExecute = true`.

The **workaround** is to **perform the output capturing *as part of the elevated process* by sending the output to *files***, which in turn requires you to **call *via a shell* and use its redirection features, namely `>`** (short of the specific target process itself offering a way to save its output to a file).

- Note: If you don't call `.WaitForExit()` up front, you should be able to capture the ongoing output in a *somewhat* timely fashion, by reading the output file as it is being written, though output buffering of the file being written may get in the way (if so, you could use .NET APIs from PowerShell to write in a non-buffering manner instead of using just `>`, but that requires more effort).

Since you're calling PowerShell (i.e. a shell) anyway, you can just incorporate redirections to (temporary) files and read them on the C# side afterwards; e.g.:

```cs
var tmpFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
await run.RunCommand(
  $"Stop-Process -Name \\\"Docker Desktop\\\" *>\\\"{tmpFile}\\\"", 
  "powershell",
  true); //Command #1
// Now examine the contents of tmpFile
```

Note:

- `*>` is used as the [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) so as to capture *all* of PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) in the target file (you could capture error output separately, however, with `2>`).
- Also note that you're better off using just *one* PowerShell process to run all your PowerShell commands, and that there's a [`Restart-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service) command that combines `Stop-Service` and `Start-Service`; simply sequence the commands with `;`

---

<sup>[1] As a *GUI*-focused function, it isn't too surprising that it has no features relating to *console*-subsystem applications and their output streams (stdout, stderr).</sup>

Comment: _cannot directly capture an elevated process'_ >> VS2022, and application have requirement to run as administrator.

Comment: Understood, @FranciscoNuñezIALover, and that is why this answers shows you a _workaround_ for this scenario. Is there something unclear about the explanation or how to implement the workaround?

Comment: I have already read the answer and despite it making sense and being true, this now causes me certain inconveniences, such as tracking the output of the commands to be executed, in the implementation that I am doing I try to fill a richtexbox with the output... According to this answer I will not be able to do it in **real time** and I will need to do it to a file...

Comment: the other problem is that in your answer there is no way to detect: when executing the docker-desktop stop command, detect when docker-desktop has been completely closed...

Comment: I don't want to contradict you, we can create a chat to talk, I think not what you indicate in your answer or it is 100% correct in my current scenario but it is too long to explain it... apparently UseShellExecute = fale; in .net-8.0 if you do it with elevated privileges.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover: If you don't call `.WaitForExit()` up front, you should be able to capture the ongoing output in a _somewhat_ timely fashion, by reading the output file as it is being written, though output buffering of the file being written may get in the way (if so, you could use .NET APIs from PowerShell to write in a non-buffering manner instead of using just `>`, but that requires more effort). I don't understand your comment afterwards ("no way to dectect ...")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256965/discussion-between-mklement0-and-francisco-nunez-ia-lover).